# Java Pass by value understanding

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I think I understand that it is a copy of the object/data member passed into the method `tricky()`, as only the value is what matters, not the actual object itself. But the print statements assure me that `arg1` and `arg2`, the copies, are indeed switched within the method. I don't understand why this wouldn't relay the information back to original objects, consequently switching them; Seeing as the method is able to successfully access the `arg1.x` and `arg1.y` data members within the method.

```
// This class demonstrates the way Java passes arguments by first copying an existing
// object/data member. This is called passing by value. the copy then points(refers)
// to the real object

// get the point class from abstract window toolkit
import java.awt.*;

public class passByValue {


static void tricky(Point arg1, Point arg2){

  arg1.x = 100;
  arg1.y = 100;
  System.out.println("Arg1: " + arg1.x + arg1.y);
  System.out.println("Arg2: " + arg2.x + arg2.y);

  Point temp = arg1;
  arg1 = arg2;
  arg2 = temp;
  System.out.println("Arg1: " + arg1.x + arg1.y);
  System.out.println("Arg2: " + arg2.x + arg2.y);
}




public static void main(String [] args){

  Point pnt1 = new Point(0,0);
  Point pnt2 = new Point(0,0);
  System.out.println("X1: " + pnt1.x + " Y1: " +pnt1.y); 
  System.out.println("X2: " + pnt2.x + " Y2: " +pnt2.y);
  System.out.println(" ");
  tricky(pnt1,pnt2);
  System.out.println("X1: " + pnt1.x + " Y1:" + pnt1.y); 
  System.out.println("X2: " + pnt2.x + " Y2: " +pnt2.y);  

}
}
```

Comment: @Lion Not true, primitives are passed-by-value. If I recall correctly, all Objects *are*.

Comment: @Lion Actually, Java's semantics dictate that objects are pass-by-reference(-by-value) and primitive types are pass-by-value.

Comment: References are passed by value and primitives are passed by value. There are no other kinds.

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) question.

Comment: That beautifully cleared it up. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does pass by value, but what it passes is the value of the object's reference, which gives the effect of pass by reference (for primitives, it behaves more like pass by value).

But Java is *always* pass by value.

Comment: To clarify, Java objects are pass-by-reference-by-value.

Comment: Um, not sure what that term means. Java is most definitely pass by value though.

Comment: The objects are passed by reference. The references are passed by value, which is I think what you're getting at.

Comment: The value of an object is it's address on the heap/stack.  When passed as a method parameter, a new variable is allocated on the stack, and the address is placed in that variable.  I've heard the term "pass by value-reference" as well to describe this.  The important part is that by modifying fields (either directly or method calls), you are changing the actual object data and the caller will see this.  However, reassignment within the method is localized to that method.  In C/C++, you get a reference with the & operator, which has no equivalent in java.

Comment: @Matt good explanation. Can't say I've ever heard pass by value-reference, but your point about reassigning shows why it is not pass by reference.

Comment: "which gives the effect of pass by reference" What the hell is "the effect of pass by reference"? Pass by reference is a semantic. It is either pass by reference or it is not.

Answer (score 5):

The object *reference* is copied, and the copied reference still points to the same object in memory. This is why you can change the object using the copied reference. However, modifying the parameter references modifies the *copies*, not the original references. This is why redirecting the references within the method doesn't redirect the references you passed in.

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

Java *is* pass by value, but when we pass an object reference, the reference value is getting pass to the method, and from there the method can change the value of object members.

Look at following code:

```
public class Passbyvalue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Animal animal=new Animal();
        animal.name="Dog";
        System.out.println(animal.name);
        testIt(animal);
        System.out.println(animal.name);
    }


    public static void testIt(Animal animal){
        animal.name="Cat";
    }

}
```

Output

Dog
Cat

This is because both reference( Original and method) are pointing to same object.

```
    __________
   |          |                 
   |          |<------------- Orignal Reference 
   | Object   |   
   |          |<------------- Method Reference
   |          |
   |__________|
```

If you want to see this effect more clearly create new object in method

```
public class Passbyvalue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal=new Animal();
        animal.name="Dog";
        System.out.println(animal.name);
        testIt(animal);
        System.out.println(animal.name);
    }


    public static void testIt(Animal animal){
        animal=new Animal();
        animal.name="Cat";
    }

}
```

Output:
Dog
Dog

Now the method reference is posting to the other Object in heap.

Answer (score 1):

Initially you new up both objects, which prints the following:

```
X1: 0 Y1: 0
X2: 0 Y2: 0
```

When you call tricky() you're passing in the reference to pnt1 and pnt2 by value and assigning those to arg1 and arg2.  So you're passing in the location in memory.  Then you print the values:

```
Arg1: 100100
Arg2: 00
Arg1: 00
Arg2: 100100
```

When you do the swap using temp, you're swapping addresses.  So back in your main method pnt1 and pnt2 still hold the original address.  So when you print you get:

```
X1: 100 Y1:100
X2: 0 Y2: 0
```

Here's a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) with some additional background.

Answer (score 0):

I used to explain this using a "graphical approach", so I hope it helps. In `main`, before calling `tricky` method you have:

```
pnt1 -> Point(x=0; y=0)
pnt2 -> Point(x=0; y=0)
```

Inside `tricky` method, `arg1` and `arg2` are copies of the `pnt1` and `pnt2` references respectively, so they are pointing to the same objects:

```
pnt1 -> Point(x=0; y=0) <- arg1
pnt2 -> Point(x=0; y=0) <- arg2
```

Through `arg1` reference, you are modifying the first Point object:

```
pnt1 -> Point(x=100; y=100) <- arg1
pnt2 -> Point(x=0; y=0) <- arg2
```

Then, you are "pointing" the `temp` reference to the first Point(100;100) object. After that, you  make `arg1` point to the same object that `arg2` is referring to -Point(0,0)-, and make `arg2` point to the same object already pointed by `temp`, i.e., Point(100;100). Therefore, inside `tricky` method you swapped the memory addresses `arg1` and `arg2` were referring to.

```
pnt1 -> Point(x=100; y=100) <- arg2 (temp also pointing this object)
pnt2 -> Point(x=0; y=0) <- arg1
```

But once the method is finished, arg1 and arg2 (and temp) are out of scope (dissapear) and you have again:

```
pnt1 -> Point(x=0; y=0)
pnt2 -> Point(x=0; y=0)
```

with `pnt1` and `pnt2` unchanged as expected, given that all changes inside `tricky` method are performed on `arg1` and `arg2`, that were only copies of references.

Hence, inside `tricky` you can change the object's contents (you have a reference to it), but you can't modify the original reference to it, as you only have a copy of it. So *Java* is *pass by value* (actually *references passed by value*).